# Unable to start firefox on centOs 6 from iterm2 on mac

Tags: mac, unix, ssh, iterm, firefox

I have installed firefox and xauth on the centOs 6.6 server as follows:

```
sudo yum install firefox
sudo yum install xauth
```

On my mac, I am using iTerm2 
On my iTerm2 session, I also exported my display as follows:

```
export DISPLAY=192.168.0.3:0.0
```

Then from my iTerm2 session I ssh to this centOs 6.6 server as follows:

```
ssh -Y server
```

Then in my centOs 6.6 server I try to start firefox as follows:

```
firefox&
```

Then I get after a long time the connection timed out error as follows:

```
$ firefox&
[1] 56352
$ connect 192.168.0.3 port 6000: Operation timed out
```

Can someone please help me fix this so that I can start firefox on centOs 6.6 using from iTerm2 on mac using ssh?

Comment: Do you have an X server running on the Mac?

Comment: No @patrix. Just checked about it here https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/M/mac_os_x_server.html - shows it needs to be purchased for 19.99. Is this mandatory? Or can I use something else which is free? Thx.

Comment: That's macOS Server, which is a bundle of applications for server related things on macOS. @patrix is talking about the [X11 windowing system.](https://www.xquartz.org)

Comment: @JMY1000 I realized it later after more researching. My bad on it. I just installed XQuartz and used its xterm. I am still trying to figure out how to start server or do I just need to use xterm and thats all. Thx

Comment: Just found https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=280461906 - it seems I am doing the same but I still get the same error.

Comment: You had already posted this question on SU https://superuser.com/questions/1277318/unable-to-start-firefox-on-centos-6-from-iterm2-on-mac Please do not crosspost the same question on multiple SE sites.

Comment: I was told to post so I did. I didnt want to. It is unnecessary more work for me to post multiple places. But I believe users do want it to be posted - perhaps because it applies/covers multiple mac here, unix there, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to open firefox now. 
**But it is extremely slow** 
And I cannot hear the sound if I play any video on youtube. 
And streaming is very chunky with missing many frames. 
So probably its useless for any practical purpose.

Following steps worked for me:

1) On centOs server:

```
sudo yum install firefox
sudo yum install xauth
```

2) On Mac - installed XQuartz and opened its terminal. 
Basically followed this link https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=280461906

**Did not export DISPLAY this time on xterm on mac.**

3) xhost +

4) ssh into the centos server from the xterm (from quartz) not iterm2:

```
ssh -Y server
```

5) Started firefox in centos from xterm:

```
firefox&
```

Comment: Why are you streaming watching video over a remote window session? Perhaps there's a better way to do this?

Comment: @JMY1000 Actually I want to run automation suite. I just tested streaming at the beginning. Even the web pages which I test with automation, when I try to load manually, they are practically unusable. I type for username to login and it appears on screen maybe around 1 minute. :(

Comment: Have you heard of [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org)?

Comment: Yes @JMY1000. My automation is using selenium. So far I was using it on 5 Windows machine. But the suite is taking more time and I wanted to add more machines to finish it faster by running more in parallel. Windows licensing is expensive, so trying to see on linux.

Comment: I'm curious then as to why you need an open X11 session. What's wrong with some VNC solution that you can just use to check in with?

Comment: Sure @JMY1000 I will try VNC. I was using remote desktop for windows earlier too. Thanks.